# How to pass 0 to TypeScript optional parameters?

Tags: javascript, typescript, optional-parameters

The following function prints out "null"

```
function foo(x?: number): void {
  alert(x || null);
}

foo(0);
```

I know that 0==null is false, so shouldn't this print 0?

Comment: It shouldn't `0` is falsy https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy + https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR

Comment: Is it possible to accept a value of 0? I'm using this for values that can also be 0 and my code works for every case except when the argument is 0.

Comment: `x` equals to `0` in your code.

Comment: @zerkms yep, and yet it prints "null".

Comment: `alert(x)` ? You're printing `null` so it prints `null`.

Comment: @ug_ you probably wanted `typeof x`, `isNaN` does something different.

Comment: @zerkms alert(0) prints 0

Comment: @AnthonyYershov that's correct. And `x || null` equals `null` if `x === 0`.

Comment: You could also check `x` using `if (x === undefined) { /* handle error */ }`

Comment: @aashah7 `undefined` cannot be passed there (if compiler is in `strict` mode)

Comment: @zerkms Okay that's one issue solved, but replacing alert(x || null) with alert(x) in the function also prints null.

Comment: @AnthonyYershov it does not - I provided you a link below with a proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

// Logical AND operation

```
true  && true;  // Result=>true
true  && false; // Result=>false
false && true;  // Result=>false
false && false; // Result=>false
```

// Logical OR operation

```
true  || true;  // Result=>true
true  || false; // Result=>true
false || true;  // Result=>true
false || false; // Result=>false
```

your alert code based on below rules:

```
false || true;  // Result=>true
false || false; // Result=>false
```

or,

```
false || any_data;  // Result=> any_data
false || any_data; // Result=> any_data
```

For more clarification:

```
alert( 1 || 0 ); // 1 (1 is truthy)
alert( true || 'no matter what' ); // (true is truthy)

alert( null || 1 ); // 1 (1 is the first truthy value)
alert( null || 0 || 1 ); // 1 (the first truthy value)
alert( undefined || null || 0 ); // 0 (all falsy, returns the last value)
```

So when x=0, it means x is false in boolean context,

```
x || null //Result=>null
```

So we can conclude **alert** will show **null**

Answer (score 1):

change the check from `(x || null)` to `x !== null ? x : null`

as `0` is falsy but doesn't equal to null

Comment: Depending on what you are going for, you might also want to expand it include `&& !isNaN(x)`. You can do this alongside the null check to also exclude NaN.

Comment: @y2bd `isNaN` is not what you wanted, really. It checks for a special `Number.NaN` value.

Comment: it still prints null :(

Comment: @zerkms applying the change suggested.

Comment: I asked to show your **actual current code** because the suggested change works perfectly https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20foo(x%3F%3A%20number)%3A%20void%20%7B%0A%20%20alert(x%20!%3D%3D%20null%20%3F%20x%20%3A%20null)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afoo(0)%3B

Comment: @zerkms here it is: function foo(x?: number): void {
    alert(x == null ? x : null);
}

foo(0);

Comment: @AnthonyYershov it outputs `null` as expected. Have you read your code?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to make sure the default value of `x` should be `null`, if nothing is passed, then you could do this

```
function foo(x: number | null = null): void {
  alert(x);
}

foo(0);
```